# Trigger a pipeline on a monthly basis in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps that would trigger every month regardless if there are changes on the git branches. This is what I have, but it's not executing.

```
trigger: none
# YAML file in the main branch
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 1 * *"
  displayName: Monthly build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - development
  always: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expression should be like `0 0 1 */1 *` which means `At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in every month.`. Please check this expression on [cron guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_*/1_*).

```yaml
trigger: none
# YAML file in the main branch
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 1 */1 *"
  displayName: Monthly build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - development
  always: true
```